# Run function when an item is selected from a dropdown

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have a dropdown in tkinter, that i have populated with some items.

```
OPTIONS = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
clicked = tk.StringVar()
clicked.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value
drop = tk.OptionMenu(frame2, clicked, *OPTIONS)
drop.place(relx = 0.65, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.08, relheight=0.6)
```

However, when a user selects a value, i want other things to happen as well.
Like returning the value to a global variable, or making the state of a button normal, so it's visible again.

How can i run a function, when an item is selected, or when a different item is selected?

EDIT:
Following the suggestions of TheLizzard, i changed my code to this:

```
# this function is triggered, when a value is selected from the dropdown
def dropdown_selection():    
   global dropdown_value
   dropdown_value = clicked.get()
   print("You changed the selection. The new selection is %s." % dropdown_value)
   button_single['state'] = 'normal'

OPTIONS = list(range(8))
clicked = tk.StringVar(master=frame2)
clicked.set(OPTIONS[0])
clicked.trace("w", dropdown_selection)
drop = tk.OptionMenu(frame2, clicked, *OPTIONS)
drop.place(relx = 0.65, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.08, relheight=0.6)
```

However, i get this error:

```
TypeError: dropdown_selection() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Try tracing `clicked` by using `clicked.trace("w", callback)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def changed(*args):
    print("You changed the selection. The new selection is %s." % clicked.get())


root = tk.Tk()

OPTIONS = list(range(8))

clicked = tk.StringVar(master=root) # Always pass the `master` keyword argument
clicked.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value
clicked.trace("w", changed)

drop = tk.OptionMenu(root, clicked, *OPTIONS)
drop.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

In tkinter you can add callbacks to variables like `StringVar` using `<tkinter variable>.trace(mode, callback)` for more info read [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111232933/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm).

Also always pass in the `master` keyword argument to all tkinter widgets/variables. You did this with the `OptionMenu` (it's the first argument usually). But you didn't do it for the `StringVar`. If you always pass the `master` keyword argument, you can save yourself a headache.

**Edit:**

When tkinter calls the callback when the variable is changed it passes some arguments (I don't think they are useful) so make sure that the callback accepts them. Instead of having `def callback()` use `def callback(*args)`.

Comment: Thank you! However, i am a bit confused as to what is the master argument. In my app, the dropdown exists inside a frame called frame2 (as you can see from the code). Does this mean that the master argument to clicked has to be frame2 as well? Like `clicked = tk.StringVar(master=frame2)`?

Comment: @user1584421 Yes. That is what the `master` argument is.

Comment: I got a weird error with the code. I updated my question with the new code.

Comment: @user1584421 change `def dropdown_selection()` to `def dropdown_selection(*args)`. I edited my answer.